# ASIHTTPRequest and web services secured

Tags: iphone, web-services, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest in my IOS application to call a wsdl/SOAP web services. my clients use a security mod ( with his ModSecurity / a PHP code).

i am using this :

```
NSData *xmlData =  // I construct the soap message witk soapui

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https:myUrlWSDL"];
self.currentRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.currentRequest appendPostData:xmlData];
[self.currentRequest setDelegate:self];
[self.currentRequest startAsynchronous];
```

But the server send to me the 400 bed request.

How i can, please, do to call my wsdl/web services with all this security mode ? what are the http headers required to call the web services ? thanks for your answers

i have disabled the secure module. now i have this error :
WSDLSOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://...?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://...?wsdl"

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASIHTTPRequest 400 bad request (soap)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301196/asihttprequest-400-bad-request-soap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how you use ASI to call a secure connection - you're doing everything correctly.

The problem must be in your code that creates the xmlData - what other error information can you get back from your clients server?

You might also need to add more headers to the request (though thats also something that your clients should be able to tell you) - e.g.

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Referer" value:@"http://allseeing-i.com/"];
```

Comment: i have disable the secure module. now i have this error :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>WSDL</faultcode><faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://...?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://...?wsdl"

Comment: That tells me it's nothing to to with security and all to do with SOAP. I know nothing about SOAP so can't help anymore, sorry! I'd ask a new question on stack overflow and mark this one as answered!